# Check if the management of the building I'm in sends late rental to credit agencies

Tags: united-states, credit-score

I'm running low on money for the next 6 weeks until I get payment for contract work I've done. In the meantime I owe to various places. I'd like to prioritize paying back to places that will report to credit agencies if I'm late. Is there a way to check if my landlord reports late payments to credit agency without asking them directly? (I'd only want to ask them as a last resort since they will then see that it's more of an incentive for me than late fee.)

Comment: Be aware that many companies have actual policies for late payments that aren't designed to screw you (a paying customer) over. Calling and saying something like "hey, I won't get paid for two months; what are my options?" is likely to get better results than you might think. (Remember to be nice to customer support.) Won't always work, but in general this is one place it's better to ask for permission rather than forgiveness.

Comment: Side note: My parents are land lords as well and always appreciate if a renter which has financial trouble talks with them about this instead of silently deferring payments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly check if a company reports to credit bureaus, though you can attempt to infer if they are likely to do so. In general, the more units the company manages, the more likely they are to report credit history. If an owner/manager has [less than 100 units that they handle, it will generally not be automatic](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/report-bad-tenants-credit-bureaus-3036.html), as the credit bureaus tend to have unit-minimums before allowing automatic reporting. However, even with one unit they can use a collection company who will handle credit reporting as part of the service. Also, the primary three credit bureaus only report payments that are made 30 days late or more.

At the same time, while you can ask them, you should know they are unlikely to be actually bound by any answer they give you if it isn't written into a binding contract.

Regardless, I think it is far more important to warn you that being late on rent usually has far more severe consequences than your credit score. 
If you want to rent another place, most places in the US require a list of your last landlord(s) and will often check with them, and can just ask them personally if you were ever late on the rent - no credit company required. This is legal in at the very least 'most' places in the US.

Landlords tend to have wide latitude in making life more difficult for you. They are generally free to refuse to continue renting to you after a lease period ends, be a stickler to rules they would otherwise overlook, insist on technically-applicable fees and fines they would otherwise not bother with, raise your rent at the end of a lease period more than they otherwise would, etc.

Most areas also allow landlords to begin eviction proceedings well before the 30 days credit bureaus care about. Many allow "5-day pay rent or quit" notices, etc, and can often demand full payment with contracted fees/penalties be paid all at once in a lump or they can continue removal processes. This whole thing is almost always more stressful and unpleasant on everyone than a few points on a credit score.

YMMV, but I personally suggest prioritizing rent to be paid on time whenever possible. There are many ways to work around other needs, from food to clothing to gas to other bills, but needing to find a new place to live or scramble to be able to stay where you are is almost always more expensive and stressful than other alternatives. I'd suggest dealing with  disconnect notices and calling to try to make extended arrangements on utilities way before paying rent late.